# Pythonanywhere deployment failure on the wsgi according to error log

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to deploy to Pythonanywhere and i believe i have followed all of the right steps.

The latest error on the error log is:

```
Error running WSGI application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Project'
    File "/var/www/sizwe93_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
       application = get_wsgi_application()

    File "/home/sizwe93/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site- 
     packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
```

My WSGI file is on the Dashboard: from this

[image]

```
# +++++++++++ DJANGO +++++++++++
# To use your own Django app use code like this:
import os
import sys

# assuming your Django settings file is at '/home/myusername/mysite/mysite/settings.py'

path = '/home/sizwe93/Project'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Project.settings'

## Uncomment the lines below depending on your Django version
###### then, for Django >=1.5:
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
###### or, for older Django <=1.4
#import django.core.handlers.wsgi
#application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I'm trying to deploy from my project on Github...

I'm not sure what i'm missing, please help...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See our help page on debugging import errors: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/